# Passing function to child component MouseEventHandler is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a React component where I want to pass an event handler from parent to child.

```
const Cards = () => {
 const hideCard = (cardId) => {
    console.log(`card ${cardId} should be hidden`);
 };

 return (
    <>
        <ChildCard
          hideCard={() => hideCard(card.id)}
         />
    </>
 )
}

interface ChildCardProps {
   hideCard: (cardId: number) => void;
}

const ChildCard = ({hideCard}: ChildCardProps) => {
      return (
         <>
             <button
                onClick={hideCard}
                type="button">Hide this card
             </button>
         </>
      )
}
```

My editor gives the follow TypeScript warning: `Type '(e: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>, cardId: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`

Is my Type declaration of the return type `void` incorrect? how do I properly type this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface of `ChildCardProps` you are telling TS that `hideCard` will be a function that will take one parameter `cardID` which will of type `number` and It will return nothing.

```
hideCard: (cardId: number) => void;
```

but the function that you are passing is not respecting this type.

You are passing a function that is not passing a `cardId` of type `number`

```
hideCard={() => hideCard(card.id)}
```

So you can declare this function as:

```
interface ChildCardProps {
  hideCard: () => void;  // REMEMBER THERE IS NO PARAMETER
}
```

Comment: I am confused how I am not passing a cardId, it's right here in the code you pasted: `hideCard={() => hideCard(card.id)}` you can see I am passing it explicitly as an argument to the function?

Comment: @randombits you are passing `card.id` in your parent component, but the function, that you pass to your child component `() => hideCard(card.id)` doesn't accept any arguments. For example, if you pass the function to the child component with a different name `hideCardChild={() => hideCard(card.id)}`. In this case, `hideCard` accepts `card.id`, but `hideCardChild` doesn't accept any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to override the `onClick` attribute of the button. you can redefine `ChildCardProps`

[check out the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-waterfall-q6xb7r?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Good point but I don't want a click event on the entire component, but a component within the component.

Comment: Then you can change`onClick={handleClick}` to `onClick={()=>handleClick()}` since you are not passing `onClick` but you are just passing a function.